# Order of consecutive determinatives

Tags: adjectives, word-order, determiners, adjective-order

Is there any accepted order for different determiners? I read in an article that “determiners” come before adjectives, but what about different kinds of determiner? For example:

> The memory of Lilian’s grandmother will always remain in her mind for all her kindness and dedication to her.

“**all**”: Quantitative determiner

“**her**”: possessive determiner

So which one is correct? “ **her all kindness**” or “**all her kindness**”? The second one sounds more natural to me, but I want to know if there is any rule.

Answer (score 3):

Only *all her kindness* is grammatical: you can think of it as an abbreviation of *all of her kindness* if that helps.  In a similar way, with a count noun, you can have: *none of her friends, some of her friends, most of her friends*, and *all (of) her friends*.